# Generic code for storing files in IsolatedStorage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have an html file containing images which are placed at local location.To read these images I am using Isolated Storage.But While storing the images in Isolated storage i need to specify the file name  which makes my code specific to those filenames.For example : I have two images abc.jpg and xyz.jpg but when these names changes to abc1.jpg and xyz1.jpg the error occurs.What can be used to write a generic code not dependent on filenames?

Comment: The terms "abc", "xyz", "abc1" and "xyz1" are identifiers.  If you change the identifiers in one place they are used but not others then surely you have to expect things to break?  I suspect infact you haven't described the issue well enough.  Your use of the word "Generic" may mislead as well since many devs see "<T>" when the word generic is used but I don't think thats what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
internal static T LoadFile<T>(string folderName, string filePrefix) where T : class
{
    string fileStreamName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.dat", folderName, filePrefix);
    return LoadFile<T>(fileStreamName);
}

internal static T LoadFile<T>(string fileStreamName) where T : class
{
    T retval = default(T);

    if (IsoStore.FileExists(fileStreamName))
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileStreamName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IsoStore))
        {
            if (stream.Length > 0)
            {
                DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (T));
                retval = dcs.ReadObject(stream) as T;
            }
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..but what does IsoStore represents here?

Comment: @IndianBird `var IsoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();` Try that :)

Comment: @SteveChadbourne:  tried what u suggested but again here i would be requiring filestreamname .what if i dont know the name and know just that it is a .jpg file ?

Comment: You can just treat it like a directory and iterate through the files in there. Use IsoStore.GetFileNames.

Comment: But prior to that files are to be saved in IsoStore with a name.I dont want to make it this storing name specific

Comment: If you want to load all of them just iterate through the files in the folder and load all of them. If you want to load specific files store the names in another file in isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

A posssible solution is:

You could use a Resources file to store these files within your xap - using File|New -> Resources File, then using Resource -> Add Existing File.

Once you've done this then the Resources File will auto generate a public Property for each resource (of type string for text files, and of type byte[] for binary files).

You can list these public properties using Reflection - something like:

```
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in MyResources.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        string propertyName = pi.Name; // the name of your resource
        object propValue = pi.GetValue(o, null); // the value of your resource

        // put your save code here - you might need to use some naming conventions to work out file extensions
    }
```